# PHP/MYSQL : date range using BETWEEN

Tags: php, mysql

[image]i have a date picker which displays the data by date range.  my query is working but there's one problem. 
For example my date range is between Jan 2017- July 2017, it will display but the year of 2016 is also displayed although i only chose the year of 2017. can you tell me what's the problem.

```
$sql = "SELECT  allinvty3.*,  soldout_bw.* , SUM(soldout_bw.qty) as totalfastqty from soldout_bw 

INNER JOIN allinvty3 on soldout_bw.itemcode = allinvty3.in_code  where soldout_bw.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('" . $from . "', '%m/%d/%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT('" . $to . "', '%m/%d/%Y') group by soldout_bw.itemcode ORDER BY totalfastqty DESC LIMIT 50 ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: print your `$sql` variable and post here please

Comment: @ArunpandianM, did you mean by this ^?

Comment: print your sql query to check whats the exacts value for `$to` and `$from` variable do `echo $sql ;` before `$result`.

Comment: It seems like you are storing your dates as a string/varchar in the format '%m/%d%Y'. So when you do your comparison, you are getting the range `07/01/2017 ... 07/22/2017`. Treated as characters (which is what you are doing), `07/22/2016` lies before `07/22/2017` but after `07/21` (and after `07/01`). So does btw `07/21/8900` or `07/21ggg59959codeSeven`. So fix your dates. You will not get happy with this format.